# I have got error while compiling dependencies added for maven

Tags: java, maven, selenium, ui-automation, maven-install-plugin

I have got error while compiling dependencies added for maven.

I have added dependency for gson 2.2.4, appium java client jar, TestNG. JDK I have used has version 1.7.

I executed mvn compile commnad to download all repositories from command prompt. Further I want to add created project to Eclipse. Please find attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Maven managed to resolve and download all your dependencies, that is not the problem.
However, it's the code in your project that is not successfully compiling:
GuestBookController.java and App.java have compilation errors that you need to fix for your maven build to succeed.

To add your project to eclipse (I assume you're using the recent versions of eclipse that come with maven plugins out of the box):
1. From eclipse, click 'File'/'Import'
2. In the import wizard, expand Maven, then select 'Existing Maven Project'
3. Click next and browse to the directory that contains your project's 'pom.xml' file.
That should do it.

Comment: Ok I will check it. Is there any other way to do android and ios device automation that I can use?